# What is the dimension of$E=\{T\in \mathcal L (V, W):Tv=0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose V and W are finite dimension. Let $v \in V$ and $$E=\{T\in \mathcal L (V, W):Tv=0\}.$$

Suppose $v \neq 0$. What is the $\dim E$?

I know that $\dim  \mathcal L(V, W)=\dim V\dim W$.

But how to deal with the condition of $Tv=0$?

Comment: The transformation $T\mapsto Tv$ is linear in $T$ and its range is all of $W$. This is because you can always find some linear transformation that sends $v$ to any vector in $W$ that you want. Therefore, its kernel, $E$, has dimension $dim(V)\dim(W)-dim(W)$.

Comment: @logarithm Why we have to minus $dim W $

Comment: Due to the [relation between range and nullity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Comment: @logarithm Thank you! I got it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can choose $v$ as first basis vector in $V$. The matrices of the maps $T$ in the question then have their first column $(0,0,\ldots,0)$ and all other columns arbitrary. It follows that you can choose $(\dim V-1)\dim W$ matrix entries to fix such a $T$, and this is also the dimension of the subspace of ${\cal L}(V,W)$ you are considering.